# Undefined reference to a function I declared

Tags: c

I'm getting these errors when I compile my code and I'm not sure how to fix them.

```
main.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to 'kToM'
main.c:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to 'kToM'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int kToM (int, float);
int mToK (int, float);

int main(void)
{
     int kilometers;
     float conversion = 1.609344;
     int miles;

     printf("Kilometers per hour converted to miles per hour:/n");
     printf("Kph/tMph/n");
     for(kilometers = 185; kilometers >= 0; kilometers - 5)
     {
         miles = kToM(kilometers, conversion);
         kToM(kilometers,conversion);
         {
             miles = kilometers / conversion;
             return miles;
         }
         printf("%f/t%f", kilometers, miles);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's the same as you try to eat half-boiled rice...

Comment: Where is your implementation of `kToM`?

Comment: in other words, you have to define the functions, declaration is not enough.

Comment: They mean "you promised me `kToM` and `mToK` would exist but they don't, so I won't compile your code".

Comment: technically it *has* compiled the code.  Those errors are from the linker.

Comment: `C` doesn't allow for functions to be defined in any scope other than global scope. You can't define it inside the loop.

Comment: This is the second question I've seen today where someone tries to define a function within the body of `main`; wonder where they're getting that idea?  Here's my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506092/functions-and-separating-a-program/40508692#40508692) to that one; might be useful.

Comment: Hey @Boo92, if my answer has helped you, would you consider accepting it? Accepting an answer shows the community that it has solved your problem, and helps future readers with theirs. If you don't know how to accept an answer, there's a useful [faq meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you need to rewrite your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int kToM (int, float);
int mToK (int, float);

int main(void)
{
    /* main function here */
}

int kToM(int foo, float bar)
{
    /* kToM function here */
}

int mToK(int foo, float bar)
{
    /* mToK function here */
}
```

You should define your functions for `kToM` and `mToK` outside of `main`.

Comment: He tried to define them, he just did it wrong. Look at the 5 lines after the function call.

Comment: Nested functions anyone?

Comment: @Supercan Well you certainly can't declare your functions in a for loop. And you also can't make function prototypes if the functions are nested in main.

Comment: @MDXF That is indeed true, however you could do it the other way around since you can declare a function inside of a function, but then again it's not a nested function. Hmm, maybe you can declare multiple different functions with the use of a for loop? *shower thoughts*

Comment: @Supercan The idea I proposed is simply the easiest/most universal way to declare functions.

Comment: @MDXF No i agree with you, just thinking out loud.